# Linux data forensics: restore pgp-encrypted file deleted with shred command

Tags: linux, encryption, pgp

Once I deleted several files by using "shred" linux command. Those files where pgp-encrypted, I have both public and private keys and I think I still remember the passphrase I used to encrypt them. As far as I remember, some of the files did contain jpeg pics archived in a zip file, which was encrypted with pgp. Other were mpeg files either alone and encrypted with pgp (or archived with zip and encrypted with pgp).
Testdisk just show those files with a size of zero.

Is there a way to create a python (or whatever) script which goes through the free inodes, get its data and try to decrypt them with pgp? I guess that would be the first step, to analyze that output.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless you have a backup in the pgp-encrypted state, you are not going to be recovering data that you `shred`ed, as that's the whole idea.

Comment: This is not a programming question and as such off-topic here.

Comment: What is the file system in question and what are the parameters it is run with?

Comment: As answer to r2d3, filesystem is ext3. I've extracted an image of it with testdisk.

Comment: Based on your response there is no answer to your question possible.